# Change State Variable Content in Contract A from Contract B

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, remix, storage

If I have two contracts, contract A and contract B.
How can I change the content of a publicly declared state variables in Contract A from Contract B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not important that the variable is `public`. It implies many things but it doesn't imply that anyone or any contract can come along and overwrite it.

`contract A` will have to explose a function. `contract B` will need knowledge of this function as well as knowledge of contract A's address. This is more than one way to address each of those concerns. As a starting point, consider.

In contract A, create a function that actually writes to the state variable.

```
function setValue(uint newValue) public returns(bool success) {
  someValue = newValue;
  return true;
}
```

in contract B.sol, inform B about the interface and location of A and instantiate an instance.

```
contract AInterface {
  function setValue(uint newValue) public returns(bool success);
}

contract B {

  AInterface a;

  function B(address addressContractA) public {
    a = AInterface(addressContractA);
  }

  function setThatThing(uint newNumber) public returns(bool success) {
    return a.setValue(newNumber);
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Rob, so without the interface approach, technically, state variables can't be overwritten by external contracts?

Comment: Right. No. The internal contract state is 100% under the control of the contract itself and no one gets around that. `public` is doing a few things, one of which is a "free" getter. It doesn't imply there is a free setter. This convenience function makes sense because there are no access control concerns on read-only functions ... everything is visible to everyone, so it makes sense to make it more convenient. Setters very often do have use-case specific access control concerns, so it makes sense to leave it to the author to decide what is acceptable.